# Ember.js -- How to bind class to rootElement?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to bind a class to my application's root element, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work.

I expected that setting the `classNameBinding` in my `ApplicationView` would do the trick, but it looks like the `ApplicationView`'s element is `undefined`. I can manually add/remove the class by targeting `$(App.rootElement)`, but I would rather do things the "ember way" if I can.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcYcU/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `App.rootElement` is the node in which your App will be rendered (by default the body tag), apart from that it doesn't do much (I think). Useful if you want to separate your Ember App from other HTML...

What you could/should consider is targeting the `App.ApplicationView` since it will be the outermost node of your App, just after the `App.rootElement`. Just need to add a class with `classNames: ['appRoot']` so you can target it in your CSS

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({

    classNames: ['appRoot'],

    isActive: false,    
    classNameBindings: ['isActive'],    

    toggleClass: function(){
        this.toggleProperty('isActive');
    },

    manuallyAddClass: function() {
        this.toggleClass();
        if(this.get('isActive')) {
            $(App.rootElement).addClass('is-active');
        } else {
            $(App.rootElement).removeClass('is-active');
        }
    }
});
```

Your CSS could have something like `#application-root .appRoot.is-active { ... }` ...